# how can I get variable declare in atd?

Tags: bash, shell

```
VDST=/home/v3000/
VDATE=20210725
echo "tar -jcf ${VDST}v3000_$VDATE.tar.bz2 --remove-files -C ${VDST} $VDATE;
      md5=($(md5sum ${VOSDST}v3000_$VDATE.tar.bz2));
      date +'%Y%m%d-%H%M%S  v3000_$DDATE.tar.bz2  $md5' >> ${VOSDST}v3000_YYYYMMDD.log" |
at now
```

In this way, I have no way to get the md5 variable here: `date +'%Y%m%d-%H%M%S  v3000_$DDATE.tar.bz2  $md5' >> ${VOSDST}v3000_YYYYMMDD.log`. How do I write to get the md5 variable?

Comment: You've got the MD5 hash value in the log — what do you mean you can't get it?  Where do you want it?

Comment: I can not get $md5 here: ```date +'%Y%m%d-%H%M%S  v3000_$DDATE.tar.bz2  $md5' >> ${VOSDST}v3000_YYYYMMDD.log```

Comment: Oh — in the assignment, you've used array notation: `md5=($(…))` but you're not using array notation in the `date` command: `${md5[*]}` looks appropriate, though you'd normally use `"${md5[@]}"` inside double quotes.  Also, the `$(…)` notations are executed before the `echo` command, not by `at`.  You may need to use single quotes around the `echo` statement (and suspend them when you need to refer to a variable defined by the shell invoking `echo` and `at`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
VDST=/home/v3000/
VDATE=20210725
echo "tar -jcf ${VDST}v3000_$VDATE.tar.bz2 --remove-files -C ${VDST} $VDATE;
      "'md5=($(md5sum '"${VDST}"'v3000_'"$VDATE"'.tar.bz2));'"
      date +'%Y%m%d-%H%M%S  v3000_$VDATE.tar.bz2  '"'$md5'" >> ${VDST}v3000_YYYYMMDD.log" |
at now
```

You can do this, although the code does not look very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

First it does not make sense to store the MD5 into an array. A scalar would be sufficient:

```
md5=$(md5sum ${VOSDST}v3000_$VDATE.tar.bz2)
```

Then, you need bash to have the variable (i.e. parameter) **expanded**. By placing it between single quotes, you explicitly tell bash to **not** expand the variable. Hence you would have to write it as

```
date "+%Y%m%d-%H%M%S  v3000_$DDATE.tar.bz2  $md5" >> ${VOSDST}v3000_YYYYMMDD.log"
```

If you really want to use an array for whatever reason, stick with your version, but then access it like an array for better clarity:

```
date "+%Y%m%d-%H%M%S  v3000_$DDATE.tar.bz2  ${md5[0]}" >> ${VOSDST}v3000_YYYYMMDD.log"
```

While you can use the plain array name and then automatically get the first element of the array, it is clearer to read if you provide the index explicitly.